# Table design for items that have revision numbers

Tags: sql, database-design

I have two tables: `CHECKLIST_INSTANCE` and `CHECKLIST_CLASS`

In `CHECKLIST_INSTANCE` I store a foreign key to the `CHECKLIST_CLASS_ID` so that I know which checklist that instance is using.

```
CHECKLIST_CLASS
   CHECKLIST_CLASS_ID
   REVISION
   NAME
```

Example data in CHECKLIST_CLASS might be:

```
  1, A, ABC Checklist
  2, A, XYZ Checklist
  3, A, QWE Checklist
  4, B, ABC Checklist
```

The problem now is revisioning.  When we revise a checklist, my current strategy is to give it a new surrogate primary key and change the Rev (as in checklist `ABC Checklist`)

I feel that with this strategy I lose the association that `CHECKLIST_CLASS_ID` 1 and 4 are related.

If I were to change the design so that I use a Combination PK for `CHECKLIST_CLASS`

```
  1, A, ABC Checklist
  2, A, XYZ Checklist
  3, A, QWE Checklist
  1, B, ABC Checklist
```

I'd then have to change my CHECKLIST_INSTANCE table to include the CHECKLIST_CLASS_REV as a foreign key and then all my queries would need to be modified too.

Another option is to add a column to `CHECKLIST_CLASS`. Either PREVIOUS_REV_ID or NEXT_REV_ID, respectively

```
  using a PREVIOUS_REV_ID field
  1, A, ABC Checklist, null
  2, A, XYZ Checklist, null
  3, A, QWE Checklist, null
  4, B, ABC Checklist, 1
```

.

```
  using a NEXT_REV_ID field
  1, A, ABC Checklist, 4
  2, A, XYZ Checklist, null
  3, A, QWE Checklist, null
  4, B, ABC Checklist, null
```

With either of the last two, I don't have to change my `CHECKLIST_INSTANCE` tables or queries. Any thoughts as to the best design? Or is there a different approach I should be investigating?

==
EDIT
Just to be clear, I am not looking for an audit trail for edits on the CHECKLIST_CLASS table.

Comment: Can CHECKLIST_CLASS.NAME change between revisions?

Comment: possibly, but we haven't done so. There is more to this than I am stating.  I also define in another table a set of questions that pertain to say ABC Checklist (referenced by just the CHECKLIST_CLASS_ID).  We add and delete questions to a checklist. Someone may decide we need to tweak its name with a revision. I'd like to keep track of revisions so that we know that which checklist and questions were used in a particular instance (workflow)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that by adding the revision to the checklist you no longer have a table with one row per checklist. Since a checklist is a distinct entity you should ensure that you have such a table.

I'd suggest that the revision moves to another table, so you now have three tables -- checklist_class, checklist_class_revisions, and checklist_instance refering to checklist_class. checklist_class could still have the most recent checklist revision in it, making the checklist revision table an historical record.

Alternatively, if it is necessary to link an instance to a revision then the checklist revision table can be the parent of the checklist instance, giving a three table hierarchy.

Comment: Alternatively, if a given checklist_instance must be associated with a specific checklist_revision, then the checklist_instance table would have to contain a foreign key referencing checklist_revision.

Comment: Yes indeed -- if that was a valid association then it would be a good choice.

Comment: Yes, I need to know that a previous checklist instance used Rev whatever.  I like the idea of having one row per checklist but then I lose the "which rev was used fact" Isn't a checklist with a specific Rev a distinct entity?

Comment: Philip, If I add the specific checklist revision to the checklist instance table then I probably need to modify some queries- was trying to take the minimalistic approach.  But if that is the best solution then that is the way I want to go

Comment: @DavidAldridge how about three tables: checklist_name, check_class, checklist_instance. checklist_name is just a two column table, id and name. checklist_class is a union table of fields checklist_name.id and rev.  This way checklist_instance still references a single pk from checklist_class.

Comment: I think I'd add a single column primary key id to the class table and reference that from the instance.

Answer (score 1):

(Replying to the reply to my comment to @David’s answer.)

Theres’ a lot of “it depends” here. One rephrased model is: [Checlikst] has many [Revisions], and [Revision] has many [Instances]. That’d be three foreign-key-related tables. The question is, does this, however, properly represent the business model that you are attempting to implement? Does it make sense to have the three separate entities? The answer to this would (at last in part) be based on how are they used. Is there value and benefit in having a [Checklist] entity independent of revisions, and an [Instance] entity that is related solely to a checklist’s revisions? Or are the [Checklist/Revisions] sufficiently independent of one another that you don’t really need the parent/child relationship? On the face of it this is denormalized data, but if there’s no true reason to normalize them out—if they aren’t separate entities—then don’t give yourself needless extra work. (Me, I’d go with fully normalized, but I don’t know the full details of your situation.)

The hard part is the “crystal ball” work: you have to make a decision based on factors that may not yet be known (i.e. what will you need to do in a week, a month, a year?) The more familiar you are with the goals and purposes of the project, the better equipped you will be to make this decision. My advice: take time, think it through, and try to avoid snap decisions you may regret tomorrow. (You’ll have plenty of time to regret the *informed* bad decisions you’ll make, but your excuses for having made them will be better.)